# FPS Rotation X in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make a FirstPersonShooter controls in three.js. I have a functionnal Y rotation for my player, but my X rotation does a barrel roll, and isn't stable (I can have my camera rotating in the left, it is very strange). Here is my game.js:

```
//import 3d
import * as engine from './three/src/Three.js'
//import GLTF Loader
import {GLTFLoader} from './three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import {OBJLoader} from './three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js'
import {MTLLoader} from './three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader.js'

//import Player
import {Player} from './src/player.js'

//make player
const player = new Player(0.1)

//Make pause variable
var isPaused = false;

//make camera
const camera = new engine.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
//change camera position
player.position.z = 3;

//create scene
const scene = new engine.Scene();
//put skyblue background
scene.background = new engine.Color("skyblue")

//create renderer
const renderer = new engine.WebGLRenderer();
//set renderer size
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
//set renderer animation
renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate)
//set renderer.domElement style and attributes
renderer.domElement.style.width = "100%";
renderer.domElement.style.height = "100%";
renderer.domElement.className = "main";
renderer.domElement.id = "main"

//light:
const ambientLight = new engine.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
ambientLight.intensity = 4;
scene.add( ambientLight );

//game logic: 

//camera:
//ask for pointer lock
renderer.domElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    renderer.domElement.requestPointerLock();
})
//Rotate the camera when mouse moving
renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousemove", player.handleMouseMove)

//Make something when pointer lock
document.addEventListener("pointerlockchange", () => {
    if (document.pointerLockElement === renderer.domElement) {
        isPaused = false;
    } else {
        isPaused = true;
    }
})

setInterval(() => {

    if (isPaused) {
        player.needToHandleMouseMove = false;
        player.needToHandleKeyboard = false;
        document.getElementById("pauseMenu").style.display = "";
    } else {
        player.needToHandleMouseMove = true;
        player.needToHandleKeyboard = true;
        document.getElementById("pauseMenu").style.display = "none";
    }
}, 20)
//Make paused in start
isPaused = true;

// END OF CAMERA
//Movement:
document.addEventListener("keydown", player.handleKeyDown)
document.addEventListener("keyup", player.handleKeyUp)
//END OF MOVEMENT
//disable scrolling
document.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {event.preventDefault();}, {passive: false});

//append the game
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//name all laoders
const glftLoader = new GLTFLoader();
const objLoader = new OBJLoader();
const mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
//load my testmap
glftLoader.load("./res/TestMap.gltf", (glftScene) => {
    var obj = glftScene.scene.children[0];
    obj.position.x = 0;
    obj.position.y = 0;
    obj.position.z = 0;
    scene.add(obj)
})


function animate(time) {

    player.checkForMovement();


    camera.setRotationFromQuaternion(player.rotation)

    camera.position.x = player.position.x;
    camera.position.y = player.position.y;
    camera.position.z = player.position.z;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

//HTML Logic:
document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", () => {isPaused = !isPaused; renderer.domElement.requestPointerLock()})
document.getElementById("menuquit").addEventListener("click", () => {window.location.href = "../../menus/index/index.html"})
document.getElementById("osquit").addEventListener("click", () => {require("electron").ipcRenderer.sendSync("closed", "close")})
```

and here is my src/Player.js:

```
import * as THREE from '../three/src/Three.js'

class Player {
    constructor(moveSpeed, keys = { W: false, A: false, S: false, D: false, ' ': false, SHIFT: false }) {
        this.moveSpeed = moveSpeed;
        this.keys = keys;
        this.position = new THREE.Vector3();
        this.rotation = new THREE.Quaternion();
        this.needToHandleMouseMove = false;
        this.needToHandleKeyboard = false;

        // Bind event handlers to the instance
        this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
        this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
        this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
    }

    // Handle Key Down. PUT IN document.addEventListener("keydown")
    handleKeyDown(event) {
        if (this.needToHandleKeyboard) {
            const key = event.key.toUpperCase();
            console.log("Key: " + key)
            if (this.keys.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this.keys[key] = true;
                if (key === ' ') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Handle Key Up. PUT IN document.addEventListener("keyup")
    handleKeyUp(event) {
        if (this.needToHandleKeyboard) {
            const key = event.key.toUpperCase();
            console.log("KeyUp: " + key)
            if (this.keys.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this.keys[key] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Handle Mouse move. PUT IN document.addEventListener("mousemove")
    handleMouseMove(event) {
        if (this.needToHandleMouseMove) {
            let movementX = event.movementX || event.mozMovementX || event.webkitMovementX || 0;
            let movementY = event.movementY || event.mozMovementY || event.webkitMovementY || 0;
            let quaternionY = new THREE.Quaternion();
            quaternionY.setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), -movementX * 0.002);
         
            this.rotation.multiply(quaternionY);



            // Create a quaternion for rotation around the X axis
            let quaternionX = new THREE.Quaternion();
            quaternionX.setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), -movementY * 0.002);

            // Limit rotation around the X axis to prevent a full roll
            let currentRotationX = new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion(this.rotation, 'YXZ').x;
            let nextRotationX = currentRotationX - movementY * 0.002;
            console.log(nextRotationX)
            if (nextRotationX < ((Math.PI / 2) -0.1) && nextRotationX > ((-Math.PI / 2) +0.1)) {
            this.rotation.multiply(quaternionX);
            }
        }
    }



    

    // Move the player with keys. PUT THAT IN ANIMATION LOOP
    checkForMovement() {
        let direction = new THREE.Vector3();
        let rotationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
        rotationMatrix.makeRotationFromQuaternion(this.rotation);
    
        if (this.keys.W) {
            direction.z -= 1;
        }
        if (this.keys.S) {
            direction.z += 1;
        }
        if (this.keys.D) {
            direction.x += 1;
        }
        if (this.keys.A) {
            direction.x -= 1;
        }
        if (this.keys[' ']) {
            direction.y += 1;
        }
        if (this.keys.SHIFT) {
            direction.y -= 1;
        }
    
        direction.normalize(); // this ensures consistent movements in all directions
        direction.applyMatrix4(rotationMatrix);
        direction.multiplyScalar(this.moveSpeed);
    
        this.position.add(direction);
    }
}
export { Player };
```

I tried a lot of things, and it doesn't works

I tried too to make this:

```
this.rotation.order = "YXZ"
```

and It doesn't work... I saw too that if I make circles with my mouse, the camera does strange things, and is left/right rotated
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKVnE.png)

Comment: Did you check out PointerLockControls from the three.js examples? https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_pointerlock

Comment: Yeah, I checked, but I didn't understand...